# Are stolen items on my horse found by guards?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

When I walk into towns I am often stopped by guards and asked to be searched for stolen items. If I'm riding on my horse, or it's right next to me, which has stolen items in it's inventory will those items be found and taken by the guards?

Also related, if they won't search my horse am I able to quickly move stolen items from my inventory to the horse while the guard is running up to me and they stay hidden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Items in your horses inventory are no longer safe with the new patch 1.3.3 (I have not noticed anything in previous patches).

I recently got stopped in town and the guard stole Han's Capons clothes that I stole from him. He left behind the lower value items that had already dropped there "stolen' tag, but took the main parts that were still labelled. (I loaded a previous save and they were 100% taken)

Not sure when this became a thing, but guards have always been able to "see" stolen goods in the horse inventory (as they make a statement about it), but now they can actually remove the items as well.

Comment: Can confirm, as of patch 1.6 if the guard confronts you, your stolen items on your horse are nabbed.  Oddly there was no other penalty for having stolen goods.

Comment: Please change your "No" in the first sentance to a "Yes". Otherwise this contradicts your answer in relation to the question title.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the horses inventory is safe from the guards prying eyes and yes, if you notice the guard before he talks to you, you can put your stolen items into your saddlebags and keep them safe.

While this method is pretty gamey, the guards recognition of stolen items is as well.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, i recently got the game and followed advice to leave stolen gear on my horse. I had an empty inventory except for a cheap sword i bought, pants, shirt, and some meat that was all mine. left my full plate i killed a guard for on my horse. Even though the horse was not present during the search they spotted and took my all my armor from my horse forcing me to reload a previous save bc i did not want to have to steal more gear and wait out that god forsaken timer that nobody knows exactly how it decides to remove the stolen tag.

I have a theory though that your horse has to be present for them to see stolen gear (my horse was standing right next to me bc i had just fast traveled) so the presence or lack thereof may be a factor here. I am going to test this now actually!!!

Answer (score -3):

No they are not safe. The guard will take the items from your horse as well.

Comment: It would be a good idea to show some sort of proof or evidence if you believe that the other, generally accepted, answer is incorrect. I've personally had stolen items and put them on my horse seconds before being searched and they are still there.